# Gauge - run @BeforeSpec in a superclass in Java

Tags: java, superclass, getgauge

I am writing a testing framework using [Gauge](https://docs.getgauge.io/).
I want some initilization logic performed in one class, and the steps logic to reuse it, like this:

```
public class A {
   protected String property = "";
   @BeforeSpec
   public void init(){
      property = "hello";
   }
}

public class B extends A {
   @Step("...")
   public void verifyProperty() {
       assertEquals(property, "hello");
   }
}
```

I can't seem to be able to achieve this. When performing the steps, the "property" is always null.
Placing the @BeforeSpec in class B and calling super.init() works, but I would like to avoid having this call in every test class that extends A.
Has anyone encountered and solved such an issue?

Comment: I think this is a bug, and should be logged [here](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a static variable:

```
public class A {
   public static String property = "";
   @BeforeSpec
   public void init(){
      property = "hello";
   }
}

public class B {
   @Step("...")
   public void verifyProperty() {
       assertEquals(A.property, "hello");
   }
}
```